# CS6 - Actionscript 3.0 Collisions, points and the lack of a bump

Tags: actionscript-3, 2d, collision

I've been toying with flash for a bit, I usually solve my problems fairly quick, however I have been stuck on this one for a few days, google hasn't been useful, and I do not have friends that know much about flash.

So, I've been working on making a basic 2D platform. I'm having problems figuring out how to implement the points on the character and bg.hitTestPoint. As it stands, before I worked the points and everything in, it was working fine. I have a trace in, to let me know when it considers it a collision with the object (In this case a wall).

The character's dimensions are:
Top Center: (42,0)
Bot Center: (42,112)
R. Center: (84,56)
L. Center: (0,56)
Total Image: 84 x 112 (px)

The character's location on the screen:
Top Center: (46, 460)
Bot Center: (46, 379)
L. Center: (20, 440)
R. Center: (80,420)

Here are the blocks:

The bump/collision variables:

var leftB:Boolean = false;
var rightB:Boolean = false;
var topB:Boolean = false;
var botB:Boolean = false;

var topBPt:Point = new Point(42, 0);
var botBPt:Point = new Point(42, 112);
var leftBPt:Point = new Point(0, 56);
var rightBPt:Point = new Point(84, 56);

The hitTestPoint block: (To save space, I'll just do the top one.)

```
if(bg.hitTestPoint(fag.x + topBPt.x, fag.y + topBPt.y, true))
{
    trace("Top Bump works.");
    topB = true;
}
    else
{
    topB = false;
}
```

```
if(topB)
{
    if(ySpeed < 0)
    {
        ySpeed *= -0.5;
    }
}
```

I tried to use different dimensions, there is a small chance I may just not have understood the full explanation on the site I was reading.

Also, I have a feeling I can work around it by just making it a hitTestObject, and manually making each part of the wall different...But I don't see that as efficient or reasonable. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Here is my entire code as a whole.

[At least it's detailed,right?)[http://snipt.org/zhaG4/Default]
(I'm sorry if it is an eyesore to anyone)

Here is the actual program as of right now:
(Physical example of the issue)[http://megaswf.com/s/2567034]

Comment: snipt.org gives 404 error. By the way, the hero passes through every obstacle like the twins in matrix.... cool

Comment: I believe I fixed the link. At least it's cool. snipt.org/zhaG4/Default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The math for finding out the collision for rectangular areas is generally the same.

First of all after glancing your code, define your screen objects as objects... I mean sublass Sprite class and add properties to it, do not do it via globals...

Like:

```
public class myScreenObjs extends Sprite {
      // Add the tricky cool specialities and properties here
}
```

Normally a sprite exposes its x and y  coordinates. If dynamically created x and y are at top left of the sprite, if via cs6 you better take the o with cross from center to top left for having a common ground of reference. Centered x y references are good for 3d specially when rotation needed.

A sprite has  width and height properties also.

Lets assume you have sprites c (character) and b (block to bump)

Given:

left   is left      x of an object.

right  is right     x of an object.

top    is top       y of an object.

bottom is bottom    y of an object.

I know this is a not very optimal function but I am writing it for demonstration purpose.

```
function bumpTest(c: Sprite, b: Sprite):Object {
var
  r: * = {},
  cLeft   : int = c.x,    // doing this for demonstrating you can directly use c.x
  cRight  : int = c.x + c.width,
  cTop    : int = c.y,   // same
  cBottom : int = c.y + c.height,
  bLeft   : int = b.x,    // same
  bRight  : int = b.x + b.width,
  bTop    : int = b.y,   // same
  bBottom : int = b.y + b.height;

  r.left   = Boolean ((cLeft  >= bLeft) && (cLeft <= bRight));
  r.right  = Boolean ((cRight >= bLeft) && (cRight <= bRight));
  r.top    = Boolean ((cTop     >= bTop) && (cTop <= bBottom));
  r.bottom = Boolean ((cBottom  >= bTop) && (cBottom <= bBottom));
  r.bump   = Boolean ((r.left || r.right)&&(r.top || r.bottom));
  return(r);
}
```

Now r has the complete answer, If r.bump is false the other values in r are irrelevant.
If r.bump turns to be true, then you can check via r.left etc from where c bumps into b. since:

r.left true means c left   is into or at boundary of b.

r.right true means c right  is into or at boundary of b.

r.top true means c top    is into or at boundary of b.

r.bottom true means c bottom is into or at boundary of b.

Comment: While this response did not solve my issue at hand, I learned a bit more, which is great in itself. I will try to detail the issue a little better.

Comment: To solve your issue you have to build the code above into a function passing b and c to it and map the coordinates.. For instance instead of c.left you can do this var cL : int = c.leftCenter.x; etc... sorry I do not know exact property names and structures you use in your objects.

Comment: I attached the code, in case you would like to take a look at it.

So, would it be something like this?
[code] 
        
var playerLeft:Point = new Point(0, 56);
var playerRight:Point = new Point(84, 56);
[/code]

I actually coded it like that before, just with crappy names.
Perhaps my issue is just the coordinates...?

Comment: @DouglasHarding Give a try now.